# What can I compute given the following values

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

We are considering a simple linear model $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \epsilon$. I am given the following quantities. $\bar{X}$, $\bar{Y}$, $s_x$, $s_y$, $\rho_{xy}$, and $n$ the sample size. I am asked to compute all of the following: $\hat{\beta_0}$, $\hat{\beta_1}$, $s_{\beta_1}$. $s_{\beta_0}$, and all the values in the ANOVA table(SSR, SSE, SSTO). I understand how to compute the values for the least squares estimators, but I dont understand how to compute their standard deviations or compute the ANOVA statistics without the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

See [*Fitting the regression line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line) section on Wiki on simple Linear regression for the first two. See the *Normality assumption* section on the same page for the latter two.

For the Anova table figures, use that $R^2$ is $\rho_{xy}^2$, recall the connection between $(s_y, n)$ and SSTO and the connection between SSR, SSE, SSTO and the $R^2$.